# Python Beginner - Summing values in a predefined interval

Tags: python

I have a rain hourly measurements series, one register per hour

I need an output with the accumulated rain per day

I am trying the code below. For the first day its ok, but for the second one and forth it doesn't work

data = [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.2 14.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  0.2  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.6  0.   0.   0.
  0.   0.   0.2  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.6  0.2  4.2  0.   0.   0.   0.2
  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  0. ]

b = 24  # day window, with 24 measurement, one per hour

x=np.arange(0,6133,1,int)

day = np.zeros((6132,1))

for i in x:

```
if i < b:
    day[i] = data[i]

else:
    cum_day = np.sum(day)
```

print(cum_day)

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would give a little more context regarding what you are trying to accomplish -- if we understand what you are trying to do, we might be able to suggest a more fitting solution.

Comment: Can you fill the part of the code which sets value on `n` ?

Comment: The input is a hourly rain measurement series, where I have 6132 records in around 256 days...I need an output with the rain accumulated along each day, the rain accumulated in each 24 hours (24 logs) –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You only need a numpy.

You have an array which has 6132 length. The length is not exactly divisible by 24.

So I append zeros to your data to make your data is exactly 256 day's data

```
data = [...] # 6132 hour datas in this array.
length = len(data) # it might be 6132
total_number_of_days = round(length/24 + 0.5) # number of days of your data
numpydata = np.array(data) # make a numpy array
numpydata = np.append(numpydata, [0]*(total_number_of_days*24-6132)) # append missing hours
datas_per_days = np.split(numpydata,total_number_of_days) # split array by number of days. (length of each row must be 24)
accumulated_rain_per_day = np.sum(datas_per_days,axis=1) # calculate rain per day...
print (accumulated_rain_per_day)
```

this code will give you rain datas per a day.

accumulated_rain_per_day[0] # first day

accumulated_rain_per_day[1] # second day...

accumulated_rain_per_day[2] # third day...

......

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing to filter the values since you already have a NumPy array. `x<b` gives you the indices where the values in `x` are below `b`. YOu pass those indices as an argument to `x[]` which gives you a subarray of only those values which are less than `b`. `x[x>=b]` gives you the values greater than or equal to `b` and then you simply sum them. If this is not what you want, please explain what you mean by intervals of 24. Provide a sample input and output

```
n = 10
b = n-1
x=np.arange(0,6133,1,int)

day = x[x<b]
cum_day = np.sum(x[x>=b])
print (cum_day)
```

**Output**

```
18803742
```

Comment: Hi @Bazingaa, actually I have a rain series, where I have hourly measurements, I want to define the rain accumulated in a day, for that 24 is my "window'.. now I have the code below, but it just works for the first day                                                                                        
#data comes from a file loaded above in the code 
b = 24 # day window, with 24 measurement, one per hour

x=np.arange(0,6133,1,int)

day = np.zeros((6132,1))

for i in x:
    if i < b:
        day[i] = data[i]
    else:
        cum_day = np.sum(day)

print(cum_day

Comment: Using a simple example as an input, can you be more specific on what you want as an output? Otherwise, it's all speculative and like chasing a ghost

Comment: The input is a hourly rain measurement series, where I have 6132 records in around 256 days...I need an output with the rain accumulated along each day, the rain accumulated in each 24 hours (24 logs)

Comment: It's better if you add some sample data, let's say for just 3-4 days in your question.